# Как target_include_directories понимает, какой заголовочный файл нужно использовать? Почему не нужно явно указывать имя заголовочного файла?

Tags: c++, cmake

У меня есть такой каталог

```
C:.
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   main.cpp
│
├───include
│       dog.h
│       log.h
│       operations.h
│
└───src
        dog.cpp
        log.cpp
        operations.cpp
```

Я хочу создать статическую библиотеку operations.lib. Для этого у меня есть такой CmakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project (HelloApp 
        VERSION 0.0.1
        DESCRIPTION "The leading Hello World App"
        LANGUAGES CXX)



# static library creation
add_library(operations STATIC src/operations.cpp)

# вот тут возникает вопрос: как Cmake узнает, что в папке include нужен именно файл 
# operations.h
target_include_directories(operations PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_compile_features(operations PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
# static library creation

add_executable(HelloAppBinary main.cpp 
        src/dog.cpp
        src/log.cpp)



        message("The path is:" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_include_directories(HelloAppBinary PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_compile_features(HelloAppBinary PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
target_link_libraries(HelloAppBinary PUBLIC operations)
```

Статическая библиотека генерируется, с этим всё в порядке.

Вопрос в следующем: как Cmake узнает, что для создания библиотеки ему нужно заинклудить
именно operations.h, а не оставшиеся заголовочные файлы (dog.h,log.h)? Мои догадка, что он это делает по прототипу функции (которая становится ему известной из-за тела фукнции в operations.cpp) , так ли это? Это ли является причиной, почему не нужно явно указывать имя заголовочного файла (operations.h)?

Comment: cmake понятия не имеет, что нужно или не нужно заинклюдить. Собственно cmake ничего и не инклюдит.  `target_include_directories` добавляет путь к папке в список путей, которые препроцессор будет использовать при поиске загаловочных файлов, включаемых в коде не в форме относительного пути. По сути это хитрый способ добавить аргумент в командную строку компилятора, не более.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как Cmake узнает, что для создания библиотеки ему нужно заинклудить именно operations.h

Никак не узнает. Ему неважно, какие конкретно хедеры соотвествуют статической библиотеке.

`target_include_directories( ... PUBLIC ... )` делает две вещи:

- При сборке самой библиотеки, добавляет эту папку в список путей, в которых компилятор ищет инклуды. (Вероятно флагом `-I`, если это GCC.)
- То же самое делает при сборке того, что зависит от этой библиотеки.

И там и там CMake-у достаточно знать только папку, а не конкретные хедеры в ней.

Comment: угу, понял, то есть как -I в обычных make-файлах было в gcc

Answer (score -4):

Да, ваша догадка верна. CMake узнает, какие заголовочные файлы нужны для создания библиотеки, исходя из того, какие файлы и функции включены в проект.

В вашем случае, CMake определяет, что заголовочный файл operations.h нужен, потому что он включен в файле operations.cpp. Во время компиляции operations.cpp, CMake будет знать о существовании operations.h и включит его в статическую библиотеку.

Вы не должны явно указывать имя заголовочного файла (operations.h), потому что CMake самостоятельно находит его, основываясь на файле исходного кода и его включенных заголовочных файлах.

Comment: Сначала пишете, что автор прав, а потом пишете не то, что у него в вопросе. Он думает, что компилятор как-то разбирает прототипы функций... Минус не мой.

Comment: *CMake узнает, какие заголовочные файлы нужны для создания библиотеки* - если бы это на самом деле было так, то ему бы цены не было...

Comment: Ответ выглядит как вывод ChatGPT.

Comment: arrowd - на самом деле так и есть, интересно было узнать кто догадается) вообще нейросеть очень часто говорит полезные вещи, в данном случае она возможно не до конца поняла вопрос

Comment: @TaLaHT [ChatGPT не разрешают использовать](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) для генерации ответов. Далее если бы разрешали, нужно указывать авторство, а то это плагиат (за который маленьким программистам массируют копчик).